# How to find the most recently accessed File Explorer window

Tags: explorer, z-order

I am trying to identify the most recently accessed (used) File Explorer window on the Desktop. I used EnumWindows to filter down all the top-level windows, and I end up with a set that looks more or less the same as what you would see in the ALT-TAB display.

I would like to bring the most recently accessed File Explorer window to the foreground, but I have two problems.

First, how to identify the explorer windows. Using the window title is not possible because the title depends on the visited folder. I think I can identify them by using the window handle to get a processID and using the processID to get a process name, class name, or executable file that started the process (e.g. "explorer.exe" or "CabinetEtc".)

Or, I could use EnumWindows for other windows and use a Shell32.Shell call to get a list of Shell32.ShellFolderView windows directly. So, let's assume I can identify a set of three or four windows that are file explorer windows.

Second, how can I tell which is the most recently accessed one? I'm thinking I could look at the z-order somehow, and pick the window that is highest in the z-order. I don't know how to access the z-order, although I have read about it in the docs.(I also hope there is one z-order list per desktop since I have three monitors and the explorer windows could be on different monitors.)

Or maybe there is a timestamp for the most recently accessed explorer window that I haven't seen in the API docs?

If someone could point me in the right direction to an example or doc on how to find the MRA window within a set of windows, I would be grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find anything on finding the most recently used file explorer window specifically. This is going to sound simplistic, but after doing quite a few experiments, it looks like the list of windows returned by FindWindows is in MRU order.

So, to find the most recently used window of a particular type/class, I use FindWindows to list a set of windows and then search down through the list to find the first match. That first match seems to be the MRU window that I am after.

For example, suppose I FindWindows all windows that have a non-empty Title string and then use foreach to loop through the set in the normal looping way. The first match found looks like it is the MRU window (at least it was in all of my manual test cases).

I have no proof that this algorithm works when windows might receive activation messages or whatever to change their position in the FindWindows output list. I was only searching for the MRU window that was manually activated by the user.

One unresolved puzzle is that the window for Dragon NaturallySpeaking was always on the top of the list. Maybe it has set the AlwaysOnTop property for itself, or maybe it is always active and is the top MRU window in the list for some reason. Something is going on there, but I don't know what.